# Pre allocate ids

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an import to multiple tables, and would like to pre-allocate ids in the various tables, so that I can prepare all of the data without locking the tables.

Previously I have used this to allocate the ids, but it requires a full tablelock, so when I am running it with a very short `lock_timeout` it can sometimes take quite a while before the ids are allocated.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  DECLARE @id bigint;
  DECLARE @id2 bigint;
  select top 1 @id2 = id from {0} WITH(SERIALIZABLE, TABLOCKX);
  select @id = IDENT_CURRENT('{0}') + 1;
  select @id2 = @id + {1} - 1
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ( {0}, RESEED, @id2);
  SELECT CAST(@id AS BIGINT)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Is there a way to pre-allocate the ids without having to take a full table lock?

Comment: Have you considered to use a SEQUENCE?

Comment: Locking while inserting 76,125 rows (or making significant changes to a table) is actually kind of important. Especially when you're saying `TABLOCKX` - what did you expect other than a full table lock?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but remember that sequences don't allow transactions, hence you cannot rollback it.

If you always need 2 ID's you can set INCREMENT BY 2

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MySeq]
AS integer
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 2;
GO
```

And then in you code:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @id bigint, 
        @id2 bigint;

    SELECT @id = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[MySeq];
    SET @id2 = @id + 1;
END
```

Comment: I don't see how the sequence allows me to allocate 76125 ids if that's what I need this time?

Comment: Then set INCREMENT BY 76125 or call 76125 times the function

Comment: Changing the increment would require a full lock on the sequence, which is almost the exact same problem as above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, in the meanwhile you don't block the table, and IMHO you don't need to change INCREMENT BY, instead you can `SELECT @id = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[MySeq];` as many times you need it. I've used INCREMENT BY 2 according the example of your question.

Comment: If you want to reserve a range of 76,125 values, you can make a single call to [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql). But that won't stop other people or processes from trying to insert those same values before you're done. And let me understand, you want to make an exclusive change to the database without taking any locks on ***anything*** (even a seqeunce)? You may want to brush up on locking, why it exists, and why it's actually what you want in write scenarios.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ofcourse not, locks are a key element of a dbms. I just want to avoid the table lock to allocate the ids. I.e. I would prefer if there was a version of ¨DBCC CHECKIDENT ( {0}, RESEED, @id2);¨ that I could give the 76125, which only update the ident, ie just taking the latch for the ident and update it, not having to have to take the lock on the table to get the max id and prevent any inserts before I change the ident.

Comment: @Cine but if you prevented the lock and grabbed the range, what would prevent another user from grabbing the same range at the same time? _Hint: It's the lock._ Are you trying to prevent two users from changing `CHECKIDENT`? Or are you just trying to make it so that readers don't have to wait for the 0.0025 seconds that takes? If the latter, consider other things that let readers read unimpeded, like RCSI. Just make sure you're actually trying to solve a real (and the right) problem. And remember that as soon as you release any locks (or don't take any), anyone can try conflicting inserts.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The problem is not the amount of time the lock is kept, or that a lock is needed, the problem is obtaining the lock. A full table lock requires all other edits to be completed before it can be obtained, and all others have to wait until it has been obtained. Whereas, in reality I dont really need a lock on the table, I just need a lock on the ident value and update that, ie instead of block all work on the table, I just need to block the allocation of new ids, ie a subset of what an insert does.